# Can I check in app purchase receipts using parse?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm playing with the in app purchase tools in parse. Am I right in saying there's no way to currently check receipts for previous purchases using the api? I'm trying to avoid getting elbow deep in ssl etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that is correct.

You can validate receipts as the transaction occurs as long as you host downloadable content on parse
https://parse.com/questions/ios-receipt-validation-after-purchase

Or you can restore previous purchases by calling `[PFPurchase restore]`
https://parse.com/questions/restoring-in-app-purchases

But nothing else from what I could find when I was looking last month (August 2014)

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess if I store something in the keychain on purchase it's might be as good.